# HTTParty File Upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest-client, httparty

I'm trying to upload a file to slack-channel using Ruby and when I do it through HTTParty, I get the error, while same options through rest-client gets it done. Is there any issue with HTTParty or am I doing it wrong?

```
options = {token: t, attachments: File.new(f,'rb'), channels: c, initial_comment: 'testing 123...'}
# t,f,c hold appropriate values

# Using Restclient:

RestClient.post url, options
# response:     <RestClient::Response 200 "{\"ok\":true,...">

# Using HTTParty:

HTTParty.post(url, body: options)
# response:    {"ok"=>false, "error"=>"no_file_data"}
```

Since it is error with file data, I also tried using File.open and File.read while using HTTParty, which resulted in same error.

Comment: ArgumentError: Content-Length not given and Transfer-Encoding is not `chunked'

Comment: Are you calling both methods in the same block of code?

Comment: @dbugger Ofcourse not, I have to use one of these which supports my use case in the best way.